# (Hadoop) MapReduce - Chain jobs - JobControl doesn't stop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, chain, job-control

I need to chain two MapReduce jobs. I used JobControl to set job2 as dependent of job1.
It works, output files are created!! But it doesn't stop!
In the shell it remains in this state:

```
12/09/11 19:06:24 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/09/11 19:06:25 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/09/11 19:06:25 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/09/11 19:06:25 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/09/11 19:07:00 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/09/11 19:07:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
```

How can I stop it?
This is my main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();

    Job job1 = new Job(conf, "canzoni");
    job1.setJarByClass(CanzoniOrdinate.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(CanzoniMapper.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(CanzoniReducer.class);
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    ControlledJob cJob1 = new ControlledJob(conf);
    cJob1.setJob(job1);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path("/user/hduser/tmp"));


    Job job2 = new Job(conf2, "songsort");
    job2.setJarByClass(CanzoniOrdinate.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(CanzoniSorterMapper.class);
    job2.setSortComparatorClass(ReverseOrder.class);
    job2.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(CanzoniSorterReducer.class);
    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    ControlledJob cJob2 = new ControlledJob(conf2);
    cJob2.setJob(job2);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("/user/hduser/tmp/part*"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));

    JobControl jobctrl = new JobControl("jobctrl");
    jobctrl.addJob(cJob1);
    jobctrl.addJob(cJob2);
    cJob2.addDependingJob(cJob1);
    jobctrl.run();


    ////////////////
    // NEW CODE ///   
    //////////////


    // delete jobctrl.run();
    Thread t = new Thread(jobctrl);
    t.start();
    String oldStatusJ1 = null;
    String oldStatusJ2 = null;
    while (!jobctrl.allFinished()) {
      String status =cJob1.toString();
      String status2 =cJob2.toString();
      if (!status.equals(oldStatusJ1)) {
        System.out.println(status);
        oldStatusJ1 = status;
      }
      if (!status2.equals(oldStatusJ2)) {
        System.out.println(status2);
        oldStatusJ2 = status2;
      }     
     }
    System.exit(0);
```

}
}

Comment: I solved it using a Thread to start JobControl. I checked that jobs have been done using a while cycle: while(!jobctrl.allFinished()) and a System.exit() out the cycle.
Now I would like that jobs return information messages, all I obtained is to know which job is in running, with ControlledJob.toString(). I don't know how get information messages as: number of mapper task, number of reduce task, records in input or in output etc... any idea to get these messages?

Comment: Is "job.getCounters().toString()" enough?

Comment: Is this a bug in JobControl class?

Comment: This is actually really useful just to see a working example of how to chain MR jobs together. Couldn't find a clear explanation on this anywhere!

Comment: @PietroLuciani Also, for the less experienced, seeing the code you used to stop your job would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, i wrote code two years ago, this evening or tomorrow i'll try to research code.

Comment: Hi, 
@Austin A, i edit my message with code requested by you.

Comment: Thanks @PietroLuciani, I haven't done a whole lot with threading so this is really helpful to me!

Answer (score 6):

I essentially did what Pietro alluded to above.

```
public class JobRunner implements Runnable {
  private JobControl control;

  public JobRunner(JobControl _control) {
    this.control = _control;
  }

  public void run() {
    this.control.run();
  }
}
```

and in my map/reduce class I have:

```
public void handleRun(JobControl control) throws InterruptedException {
    JobRunner runner = new JobRunner(control);
    Thread t = new Thread(runner);
    t.start();

    while (!control.allFinished()) {
        System.out.println("Still running...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

in which I just pass the jobControl object.

Answer (score 3):

The JobControl object itself is Runnable, so you can just use it like this:

```
new Thread(myJobControlInstance).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tweak to the code snippet what sinemetu1 had shared..

You can drop call to the JobRunner as JobControl by itself implements Runnable

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(jobControl);
        thread.start();

        while (!jobControl.allFinished()) {
            System.out.println("Still running...");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
```

I also stumbled upon this link where the user confirms that JobControl can be run ONLY with new thread.
https://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg00556.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Thread jcThread = new Thread(jobControl);
    jcThread.start();
    System.out.println("循环判断jobControl运行状态 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    while (true) {
        if (jobControl.allFinished()) {
        System.out.println("====>> jobControl.allFinished=" + jobControl.getSuccessfulJobList());
        jobControl.stop();
        // 如果不加 break 或者 return，程序会一直循环
        break;
    }

    if (jobControl.getFailedJobList().size() > 0) {
        succ = 0;
        System.out.println("====>> jobControl.getFailedJobList=" + jobControl.getFailedJobList());
        jobControl.stop();

        // 如果不加 break 或者 return，程序会一直循环
        break;
    }
}
```